# Why can't I stop the music in a loop in Scratch?

Tags: loops, audio, mit-scratch

I am making a game and I need title screen music. I added all the code and it doesn't stop playing, it just restarts the music. How do I fix this?

I have tried using a repeat until block but it still doesn't work, it just waits until the music is done then it stops.

The play button code:

```
when this sprite clicked
start sound coin
broadcast game
repeat 10
    change ghost effect by 10
end of repeat block
hide
```

The backdrop code:

```
when i receive game
repeat 10
    change ghost effect by 10
end of repeat block
switch backdrop to game
```

```
when backdrop switches to game
repeat 10
    change ghost effect by -10
end of repeat block
forever play sound music until done
```

I expect the output to stop the title screen music, but the current output is it restarting the music, then when it's finished it stops.

Answer (score 2):

In the music section, there is a block called "Stop All Sounds".

Use this block to stop all sounds but add a 0.3 second delay before stopping all sounds so it doesn't stop the sound in the forever loop below. 
[Here is a picture (ctrl + click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTpdU.png)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to change the code to this:

```
when backdrop switches to game
repeat 10
    change ghost effect by -10
end of repeat block
forever play sound music until done
stop all sounds
stop this script
```

stop all sounds will the song, stop this script will make the loop stop

Comment: Can code after a `forever` ever be executed? That would go against the meaning of the word "forever".

Comment: No, it cannot. That's why the `forever` block has a bottom border without any connector.